# get enumMember value property from an enum

Tags: c#, enums, jsonconvert

I have an enum like this :

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public enum Process
    {
        [EnumMember(Value = "N/A")]
        None,
        [EnumMember(Value = "Something")]
        Something
     }
```

When I try to read its value like this:

```
Process.Status = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Process.None);
```

I am getting 0
ALso toString() doesn't work as I get "None" and not "N/A".
How do i solve this?

Comment: you probably need to provide the converter like this: SerializeObject(
 Object value,
 params JsonConverter[] converters
)

Comment: [Works for me](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jOMjkp).

Comment: Did you mix Json.Net and System.Text.Json?